# PhpStorm - remove 200 responses from console when using built in PHP server

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.2

I am using PhpStorm and tried yesterday to use the built-in server functionality that it provides.

It works, but I find the console showing in bright red the 200 responses quite annoying, as it makes quite hard to spot real issues.

In the picture below you'll see what I mean.

[image]

Is there any way to disable these and only show for instance warnings (maybe in yellow) and errors (maybe in red)?

Comment: I'm not using PHP's built-in web server myself .. so not 100% sure if it will work .. but **Grep Console** plugin allows to: 1) change color for the whole line based on presence of some marker ... or 2) even hide/remove such line completely. Try it -- it may work for this console as well (it work in normal "execute process/task" windows so should work here as well). Your marker here could be `[200]:` or alike.

Comment: could you please point me to an example please? I never used grep and I am a bit of a noob when working with the console

Comment: It will be very basic for you. The plugin called **Grep** Console .. but highlighting will be a simple string -- just `[200]:` (no regex involved). If it will not work for some reason -- just convert it into regex: `.*\[200\]:.*` -- something like that should work. Example of how it works: https://postimg.org/image/fup1yn0ot/ The rule is highlighted (plain string as it's simple one): https://postimg.org/image/5lwkstcn1/

Comment: Thanks, that did work perfectly fine. Thanks again, and if you want to put this as an answer I can then select it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **Grep Console plugin** for this -- should do the job fine (does so in similar consoles).

Based on your requirements it allows you to:

- change color for the matching text (or whole line if desired) based on presence of some marker (matching text)
- or even hide (filter out) such line completely.

Your marker here could be `[200]:` for successful responses -- this is a simple "match the exact text" pattern. If it does not work (e.g. because this text is in the middle of the string .. or because it looks like regex (as `[]` have special meaning in regex)) then just convert it into proper regex: `.*\[200\]:.*` -- something like that should do.

---

Example of how it works:

[image]

The rule for that is highlighted (plain string as it's a very simple rule -- match exact string):

[image]

Comment: As a small note, I had to use the regex.

Comment: Quite possibly -- I'm using this plugin for 4 or so years now (maybe even 5) .. but last rule I've created was like 2 months after starting using it ... so it may indeed require regex for matching text in the middle of the line (otherwise it will be simple matching of whole string)

Comment: It still works, so it doesn't really matter! thanks again for the help